# Divs next to each other CSS height issue in a wrapping container

Tags: html, css

I'm building a simple HTML and CSS page where I did a container which includes 2 other divs next to each other but the issue I have is the one showed in the screenshot:

[image]

As you see the divs height stops and I cannot understand what I did wrong.
I added the snippet which shows exactly my issue. Most probably it is a stupid error I did which I cannot see it.

```css
/* Default Styles*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lexend+Deca&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.presentation {
    padding: 50px 0;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.container {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    line-height: 1;
    position: absolute;
    right: auto;
    left: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Lexend Deca', sans-serif;
}

h5.title {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: #000000;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

p {
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

/* Left Side Bar */
.inner-left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 16%;
    top: 5%;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 15%;
    background: #fff;
    margin-left: -16px;
}

.inner-left img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.inner-left .personal-info {
    position: relative;
    padding: 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

.inner-left .personal-info li span {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.inner-left .personal-info li p {
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.inner-left .personal-info li span {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
}


/* Right Main Container */
.inner-right {
    position: absolute;
    left: 32%;
    right: 0;
    top: 5%;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #fff;
    width: 50%;
}

.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="presentation">
    <div class="container clearfix">
      <div class="inner-left">
        <header class="bio-header">
          <h5 class="title">Personal Details</h5>
        </header>
        <img src="JakubProfile.jpeg" alt="jakub-avatar">
        <ul class="personal-info">
          <li>
            <p>
              <span>name</span> Jakub Lemiszewski
            </p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>
              <span>age</span> 34
            </p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>
              <span>location</span> Copenhagen DK
            </p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>
              <span>degree</span> BSc
            </p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>
              <span>phone</span> +45 26542598
            </p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>
              <span>email</span>
              <a href="mailto:lemiszewski@gmx.com">lemiszewski@gmx.com</a>
            </p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>
              <span>gihub</span>
              <a href="https://github.com/Jakub41" target="_blank">Jakub41</a>
            </p>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <h5 class="title">Social Profiles</h5>
        <div class="social-links">
          <ul>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="inner-right">
        <header class="bio-header">
          <h5 class="title">Who Is Jakub?</h5>
        </header>
        <div class="text">
          Descrption of my self
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: making everything `position:absolute` isn't a correct way to create a layout. I would first start correcting this.

Comment: @TemaniAfif could you please show me that in a snippet because I'm having hard time to resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues with your code (even the new fiddle). There's no reason to define the height on the `.container`. If you set it in `vh`, the element will only render as tall as the current viewport, so no matter what, you'll extend past the bottom. Let the inner content define the height.

Using relative positioning and percentages for the `left` and `top` is also not really the best way to go.

I would highly recommend using `display: flex` instead.

Here is an example:

```css
/* Default Styles*/

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lexend+Deca&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.presentation {
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.container {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  line-height: 1;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10%;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Lexend Deca', sans-serif;
}

h5.title {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

p {
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}


/* Left Side Bar */

.inner-left {
  background: #fff;
  flex: 1 1 15%;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.inner-right {
  background: #fff;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
}

.inner-left img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.inner-left .personal-info {
  padding: 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

.inner-left .personal-info li p {
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.inner-left .personal-info li span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="presentation">
    <div class="container clearfix">
      <div class="inner-left">
        <header class="bio-header">
          <h5 class="title">Personal Details</h5>
        </header>
        <img src="JakubProfile.jpeg" alt="jakub-avatar">
        <ul class="personal-info">
          <li>
            <p>
              <span>name</span> Jakub Lemiszewski
            </p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>
              <span>age</span> 34
            </p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>
              <span>location</span> Copenhagen DK
            </p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>
              <span>degree</span> BSc
            </p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>
              <span>phone</span> +45 26542598
            </p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>
              <span>email</span>
              <a href="mailto:lemiszewski@gmx.com">lemiszewski@gmx.com</a>
            </p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p>
              <span>gihub</span>
              <a href="https://github.com/Jakub41" target="_blank">Jakub41</a>
            </p>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <h5 class="title">Social Profiles</h5>
        <div class="social-links">
          <ul>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
            <li>Facebook</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="inner-right">
        <header class="bio-header">
          <h5 class="title">Who Is Jakub?</h5>
        </header>
        <div class="text">
          Descrption of my self
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I've simplified your CSS properties. In this example, I set `.container` to a flex parent. From there, I give `inner-right` and `inner-left` the shorthand property `flex`.

I can add more information about flex if needed, but here is a good resource to start.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Here's the fiddle for the answer so you can play with it:
https://jsfiddle.net/adh29m1r/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question right, but I would recommend you to use "position: absolute" only the outer divs (if necessary) and keep the inner divs relative. You should try to use 100vh (for height) and 100vw (for width) on the outer div and a relative percentage on the inner divs. 
If that is not solving your issue please show us your exact issue without to much unnecessary information (only the divs and the css which is related to it)

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer. Post some code that you think will fix the issue.

Comment: Yea I know but I cant comment, sorry

Comment: I included the code snippet in my post to show the issue and I will try your suggestions

Comment: I did this but still not working https://jsfiddle.net/jakub41/6wuozbr1/

Comment: @carl7681 I know you can't comment, that's why you need to post an actual answer. If it's accepted, you start gaining enough rep until you can comment.